# three.js how to import old JSON models using r58

Tags: import, three.js, webgl, converters

I built a THREE.JS program using older models (ginger demo). After upgrading from r44 to r58, I was no longer able to use the models that were created using version 2 of the python based OBJ -> Three.js converter. The issue, I am assuming, is due to the formatting of the files.

I do not have the original .OBJ models, so I'm trying figure out how to upgrade the older json format to the newer one so that the parser can read it. I considered importing it into the THREEJS Editor and then exporting again, but the models have morphing targets and those were not preserved using that technique.

[Here is an example](http://stickmanventures.com/labs/demo/webgl-threejs-morph-target/model/gingerhead.js) of a JSON file I'm trying to upgrade.

The following is my progress thus far: When importing using the JSONLoader, the initial error I get is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
```

That is due to commenting of metadata, so I added the commented metadata to a metadata field to match the format seen near line 160 of [this converter file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py). I also removed all other non-JSON code (variables, etc). I also got rid of the "edges" field because it was empty and I didn't find taht string in the .py code.

The json file loaded successfully, but I got the following errors when I used it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
```

The 'attributes' error repeated indefinitely.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
"metadata": {
    "formatVersion" : 2,
    "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
    "vertices"      : 168,
    "faces"         : 144,
    "normals"       : 576,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : 175,
    "materials"     : 1
},
"scale" : 1000.000000,
"materials": [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "phong1SG",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
    "colorSpecular" : [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    "illumination" : 4,
    "mapDiffuse" : "ginger_color.jpg",
    "opticalDensity" : 1.0,
    "specularCoef" : 98.0
}],
"vertices": [1900,6776,...],
"morphTargets": [],
"morphColors": [],
"normals": [-0.024569,-0.94821,...],
"colors": [],
"uvs": [[0.37164,0.65357,...]],
"faces": [43,1,...]
}
```

What is the error in my manual conversion? Is it even possible to use the same data from different converter versions? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert them using the [editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) by dragging the file into the editor and then exporting it. Sadly the exporter is not complete yet (missing UVs)...

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Is there any practical way to add the UVs?

Comment: What about morphing targets, can they be converted? That's a crucial part of the model (not depicted in my example). When I tried they did not get transferred to the new model.

Comment: Ah yep... Morph Targets aren't supported either :/